# NA answer in calculating correlation in R

Tags: r

I am supposed to write a function in R order to calculate the correlation between two pollutants of "nitrate and "sulfate" when numbers of complete cases at each file are above a specified threshold, There are 332 separate CSV files, Here is what I have got so far, however when I run it instead of a vector I will get NA answer. I'll deeply appreciate any help, thanks

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold=0) {
    data <- setwd("C:\\Users.....specdata")
    files <-list.files(data, full.names=FALSE)
    nobs <- c()
    threshold <- c() 
    correlation_list <- c()
    for (i in 1:332){
            dat <- read.csv(files[i], sep=",") 
            complete_cases <- dat[complete.cases(dat),]
            nobs <- c(nobs,nrow(complete_cases))
            good <- complete_cases [(nobs> threshold),]
            #if (nobs> threshold) {
            correlation_list <- c(correlation_list, cor(good["nitrate"], good["sulfate"]))      
            #}
            return(correlation_list)
    }
```

Comment: Manually run your code. Run the startup code, set i = 1, run the code in the loop, examine it, set i = 2, run the code in the loop, examine it. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Also note the location of where your return statement is.

Comment: Do you miss **}**   before **return(correlation_list)**  in order to close **for** ?

Comment: Also check `threshold`. You allow your user to define it as a parameter, and then you erase it with `threshold <- c()`. So `(nobs> threshold)` will always return `logical(0)`.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Correlation is covariance divided by variance, so if one of your dimensions has zero variance, you will get a division by zero.